# unexpected T_STRING, can't find a syntax error

Tags: php

I am getting the error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /mysite/my_library.php on line 43
```

However, I can not find any synatx errors in the code that it suggests:

```
/*
 * Get Full Filter Name from Abbreviation
 */
function getFilterName ($filterAbbreviation) {
    $filters = array(
        "R" => "Restuarant",
        "B" => "Bar",
        "S" => "Store",
        "L" => "Lodging",
        "Q" => "Recreation",
        "G" => "Gas Station",
        "E" => "Entertainment",
        "C" => "Club"
    );
    return $filters[$filterAbbreviation];
}
/*
 * Parse Filterstring 
 */
function parseFilterString($filterString) {
    $returnVal = "";
    $filterLetters = str_split($filterString, 1);
    for($x = 0; $x < strlen($filterString); $x++) {
        $returnVal .= "(type <=> '" . getFilterName($filterLetters[$x]) . "') OR ";
    }    
    if (strlen($returnVal) > 0) $returnVal =  substr($returnVal,0,-4); //remove final " OR " from filterstring
    else $returnVal = "type = 'VOID'";  //if everything is filtered, make sure to set type to something not available
    return $returnVal;
}
```

Please note this code is referenced from the page the user is querying using `require()`.

Comment: According to my IDE, 43 is: `$filterLetters = str_split($filterString, 1);`

Comment: Yes, 2nd line in `parseFilterString()`

Comment: There is no syntax error in your code http://codepad.org/TuEb9rPg

Comment: Then why else would I receive this error?

Comment: Because you didn't post all the code. You can debug your problem by removing parts of the code until the error goes away.

Comment: The issue is resolved if I comment out the contents of `parseFilterString()` and return `""`. I have provided all of the relevant code. :/

Comment: @PRNDLDevelopmentStudios But you haven't provided all the code that calls `parseFilterString` function..

Comment: I agree, there are no syntax errors in your code. The error message points to line 43 ¿where is it? your code has only 32 lines.

Comment: @DesmondHume I use it with: `$filterString = parseFilterString($_GET["filter"]);`. The string sent with get is `R`.

Comment: @FelipeAlamedaA There are two irrelevant methods above these two which also have no errors.

Comment: @PRNDLDevelopmentStudios Could you place `var_dump($filterString);` at the beginning of the `parseFilterString` function and tell us what it says?

Comment: It doesn't do anything. It isn't running any code because it thinks there is a syntax error.

Comment: @PRNDLDevelopmentStudios Comment out the line 43 and try again (duh :) Oh yes and maybe replace it with `$filterLetters = array();`.

Comment: haha my bad. I did that just before you posted. It returns `string(1) "R" `

Comment: Changing with `array()` string gives me the t-string error.

Comment: Have no idea then http://3v4l.org/TB8nR Sorry.

Comment: I moved `parseFilterString` to another file (instead of using `require()`) and the error moved to that file. It has to do with that method. 

Thanks for trying though.

Comment: Select the line above, the offending line and the line below (all in one go, three lines together). Hit "delete". Then TYPE (do not cut and paste), but use the keyboard the offending lines back in.

Comment: Added as answer with explination. It's an old problem, was more common about 25 years ago, but less so now as editors are generally more reliable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason (in your case) is that your editor has inserted a hidden character in the text. (The editor is a computer program, and all computer programs go wrong, sometimes!). The clue was that it appeared to complaining about a space, but a space is not a string unless surrounded by quotes, so something is wrong. And what is wrong is that it's not a space, but something else...

The solution is to remove this hidden character. The safest is to delete the line and retype it - but just in case the hidden character is within the end-line (CR/CRLF) markers, it's best to delete the lines above and below as well.

So, select the line above, the offending line and the line below (all in one go, three lines together). Hit "delete". Then TYPE (do not cut and paste), but use the keyboard to type the offending lines back in.

(Note - the this does not work, the error line may simply move. This is where delete fails to see the hidden character and only deletes the test it expects. The trick for this is to copy/paste everything execpt the offending line +/- 1 into another file, then type the offending line +/-1 into that new file. In your case, you didn't need it, I'm just adding for completeness of answer).